# Can I instantiate a member class template with member variables?

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
class NDArray{

    private:
        Context ctx_;
        typeFlag dtype_;
        std::vector<size_t> shape_;
        std::shared_ptr<TBlob<dtype_, ctx_.dev_type_, ctx_.dev_id_> > data_;

    public:
        // constructor
        NDArray(); 
        NDArray(const NDArray &obj);
        explicit NDArray(const size_t size);
```

I want to instantiate `data_` member after the constructor, where I initialize the `ctx_` and `dtype_` member

```cpp
inline NDArray::NDArray(): ctx_(Context()), shape_{0}, dtype_(typeFlag::kFloat32), {}
inline NDArray::NDArray(const NDArray &obj): ctx_(obj.ctx_), shape_(obj.shape_), dtype_(obj.dtype_), data_(obj.data_){}
```

Then I got errors:

```
NDArray.hpp:18:31: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘mxnet::NDArray::dtype_’
         std::shared_ptr<TBlob<dtype_, ctx_.dev_type_, ctx_.dev_id_> data_;
                               ^
NDArray.hpp:16:18: note: declared here
         typeFlag dtype_;
```

What can I do to achieve my goal? Could you plz help me

**EDIT**

```cpp
template<typeFlag dtype, Context::DeviceType ctx_type, int ctx_id>
class TBlob{
    friend class NDArray;

    public:
        TBlob();
        TBlob(const TBlob<dtype, ctx_type, ctx_id> &obj);
        explicit TBlob(const size_t &size);
        explicit TBlob(const std::vector<size_t> &shape);
        TBlob(const float *data, const size_t size);
        TBlob(const float *data, const std::vector<size_t> shape);
        TBlob(const uint8_t *data, const size_t size);
        TBlob(const uint8_t *data, const std::vector<size_t> shape);
        ~TBlob();

    private:
        void *dptr_;
        std::vector<size_t> shape_;
};

template<typeFlag dtype, Context::DeviceType ctx_type, int ctx_id>
inline TBlob<dtype, ctx_type, ctx_id>::TBlob(): dptr_(nullptr), shape_{0} {}

template<typeFlag dtype, Context::DeviceType ctx_type, int ctx_id>
inline TBlob<dtype, ctx_type, ctx_id>::TBlob(const TBlob<dtype, ctx_type, ctx_id> &obj): dptr_(obj.dptr_), shape_(obj.shape_) {}
```

Comment: What is `TBlob`? It looks like it requires non-type `template` arguments. If that is the case, then you cannot pass it the runtime value of objects. The values must be known at compile time. The only way this can work is if you are trying to pass member pointers. But then `ctx_.dex_type_` and `ctx_.dev_id_` would be complicated to pass.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you! I add the definition of ```TBlob```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with templates. Template arguments must necessarily be known at compile time but the values of your members are not compile time constants.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see. Thank you for your kind, I will try another way

Comment: An option would be to templatize `NDArray` as well.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Thank you! I want to avoid templating ```NDArray``` so that I make the ```TBlob``` member

Comment: @欧岳枫 You'll have to use polymorphism then (i.e virtual methods) which incurs an overhead at runtime and might potentially deprive the compiler of some optimization opportunities. Notice that it would be possible to write custom cast similliar to how you also call `np.cast` in python code. Its still possible to write generic algorithms for arbitrary dtypes by templatizing them as well. Just some ideas

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I'm new to C++, but I think your advice is attractive! Thank you and I will struggle to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest thing I can think of to what you want, but I don't know if it will be useful to you. Note there is a slight overhead due to virtual methods. I used a more simple example but it should be more or less equivalent.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

// Base interface class for the templated type
class TemplInterface
{
public:
    // Templated class (pure?) virtual method declarations
    // (parameter and return types cannot depend on template values)
    virtual void print_value() const = 0;
};

// Actual templated type
template<int i>
class Templ : public TemplInterface
{
public:
    // Templated class implementation
    virtual void print_value() const
    {
        std::cout << "Value: " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

// Class containing the templated type
class Outer
{
private:
    // Member pointer to non-template base type
    std::shared_ptr<TemplInterface> _templ;
    // Class constructor is private
    Outer(std::shared_ptr<TemplInterface> templ) : _templ(std::move(templ)) {}
public:
    // Factory function
    template<int i>
    static Outer make()
    {
        return Outer(std::make_shared<Templ<i>>());
    }
    void print_templ() const
    {
        _templ->print_value();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Outer a = Outer::make<3>();
    a.print_templ();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need some time to understand this code. It definately inspires me

Comment: @欧岳枫 Please do ask if there is something you don't understand or you feel is not clear enough. The idea is to "hide" the fact that your enclosed type is templated through a parent non-template class, and since you are already storing a (smart) pointer, you can make it to the parent type and the implementation for the actual class should work, as long as member functions are virtual.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean that I can use polymorphism to make the dtype mapping? I am still confusing that since the value 3 in your example is an const value known in compile time, what if I code: ```Outer a = Outer::make<i>();``` where ```int i``` is only known in run time? And, why ```Templ::print_value()``` is still virtual? My question might be stupid and so sorry to trouble you for these.

Comment: @欧岳枫 You cannot use a variable as a template parameter (unless it is `constexpr`, in which case is not really variable). If you are using templates, all the template parameters need to be known at compile time.

Comment: Indeed. I will put the instantiation in an ```Init()``` function to avoid using variable as parameter, I use variable as condition to select a proper template class which parameter is known in compile time. Thank you again!